# I want my header to be updated as soon as localstorage data changes

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I have a checkbox in a entirely different pop up component(renders every time user logs in)  and I'm saving the the marked checkbox in a local storage and the thing is I want to show the marked checkbox label in the header. Currently I'm doing this using redux. Is there any better way to achieve this without using redux. Header component renders before the pop up component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your value is some general value that defines the context of the application or page you could try using React Context API.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: So there is other way to do this

Comment: @AniketSaxena What is the purpose of the checkbox that you have? What does it represent?

Comment: You can think of as the text which user wants to show on the header

Comment: Got it. In this case, I would say that the context API should be a good fit for this.